# Eclipse and EGit . Push?

Tags: eclipse, push, bitbucket, egit, pull

I am using GIT as DVCS. I have a team working with me on a project.Last night when I committed changes to the repository. It caused lost of previous changes made by other developers.(I did this: 1)-Pulled the project from remote directory and then 2-)Commit and Push the files to remote repository. These are all the files that I had recently pulled from directory + my modified files) Can somebody please tell me the exact steps that I should follow to push and pull. And I should be able choose only files that are changed by me.
Thanks!
I forgot to mention that I did the "Force Update" while pushing to remote repository.

Comment: Having some issue with that right now, sad to see that nobody solved the issue for you :(